# Is $\mathbb{F}_3(t)(\sqrt[4]t)$ a splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $t$ be transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

I used the polynomial $f = x^3 - 1$ to prove that $\mathbb{F}_3(t)(\sqrt[3]t)$ a splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$. This was convenient since $f = (x - \sqrt[3]{t})^3$ in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)(\sqrt[3]t)$.

Now I have to show whether the same applies to $\mathbb{F}_3(t)(\sqrt[4]t)$. I have the feeling this is not a splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$, but to show this I somehow have to show that there is no polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ for which $\mathbb{F}_3(t)(\sqrt[4]t)$ is the smallest subset containing all of it's zero's.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Write down the roots of $X^4 - t$ over $\bar{\mathbf{F}_3}(t)$.

Comment: $\sqrt[4]t$, $-\sqrt[4]t$

Comment: All of them. ${}{}$

Comment: $\sqrt[4]t$, $2\sqrt[4]t$ <-- same thing, can't think of something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal extension is stable - invariant under ambient automorphisms. This means in particular that it contains all its elements' conjugates. What are all of the roots of $X^4-t$?

The roots aren't just $\pm\sqrt[4]{t}$, any more than they would be with $\Bbb Q(t)$ instead of $\Bbb F_3(t)$. Notice that to get the roots with $\Bbb Q$, you need to invoke primitive $4$th roots of unity. Same idea with $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: Ah, I guess I found it. The roots are $\sqrt[4]t$, $2\sqrt[4]t$, $\sqrt2\sqrt[4]t$, $-\sqrt2\sqrt[4]t$.

Comment: @user157461 It'd be more elegant to say $\pm\sqrt[4]{\pm t}$ (since then our claim is true for *any* field, not just in characteristic $3$), but yes those are the roots here.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, pressed enter to early. I found these roots by factorizing. So now I can say that the roots of $X^4 -t$ aren't all in this extension field, but how can I know there isn't another polynomial for which the roots are in this extension field?

Comment: @user157461 There is another polynomial whose roots are in this extension field, namely $X^2-t$. But we're here to prove it isn't *splitting* field. That's where the first paragraph in my answer comes in. Are you familiar with, and can you prove the facts I state in it?

Comment: Ok, great, I see now. This polynomial proves that the extension is not normal, and therefore (by a theorem in my book, for which the proof is not covered) it is not a splitting field of a polynomial. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @user157461 Well, any splitting field of a polynomial is normal basically by definition (the only difference is that normal can be the splitting field of a *family* of polynomials), so if an extension isn't normal it can't be a splitting field. There is no big theorem here. However, one does use a powerful extension theorem to show a normal extension contains all its elements' conjugates.

Comment: Ah, it's the other way around which they explicitly state they will not prove: that a splitting field of a polynomial is also a normal extension.

Anyway, this polynomial is not normal because $x^4 - t$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F_3}(t)$ and has a root in $\mathbb{F_3}(t)(\sqrt[4]t)$ but not all of it's roots.

Comment: @user157461 That's what you insinuated in your previous comment, which I was replying to. It's trivial. The reverse implication, that a normal extension is the splitting field of a single polynomial (given some additional hypotheses) is nontrivial - it's essentially the primitive element theorem. Unless you are using some different definition of "normal" than I am.